# Stale/ghost TXT SPF records?

Tags: dns, mandrill, spf

I am trying to use mandrill to do transactional emails and I cant verify the SPF because i keep running into a "website has more than one TXT record that looks like an SPF record."

I don't understand because my google domains DNS obviously does not have any other txt record other than the one from mandrill.

So i looked up my txt dns on mxtoolbox and I see 2 TXT records:

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

as well as the one I currently have

```
v=spf1 include:spf.mandrillapp.com include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

But the first one, the one with just google, is NOT in my DNS unless i'm going blind. I had replaced it with the new one. I thought maybe it just takes a little while to update the DNS so I left it for a day, but now its been over 24 hours and im still seeing this ghost spf record from google, and mandrill wont verify the SPF.

Is there anyway i can get rid of it or something?

Answer (score 0):

It will be in your DNS somewhere. Verify it using `dig` so that you can target your name servers explicitly rather than some random 3rd-party cached copy. Get your name servers with:

```
dig ns example.com
```

then pick one of the responses and ask that about your txt records:

```
dig @ns1.example.com txt example.com
```

Comment: Yeah i am getting 2 records for each reponse. I don't understand where the second one is coming from. I cant edit or see it when i am customizing my DNS

Comment: Maybe ask your DNS provider about it?

Comment: "I cant edit or see it when i am customizing my DNS" Maybe your provider is not publishing your changes on its nameservers. Maybe at one point you updated the TXT record and the provider thought it was an addition instead of a replacement, hence the 2 records now (since second one "includes" first one)